# Is WebBrowser.Stop() then WebBrowser.Navigate() Redundant?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

Are these equivalent?

```
WebBrowser.Navigate('http://google.com');
```

and

```
WebBrowser.Stop();
WebBrowser.Navigate('http://google.com');
```

The MSDN documentation doesn't say.

Comment: I can't imagine it being any other way- `Navigate()` is async, it makes sense for the request to be stopped when you start a new one.

Comment: I've been using a WebBrowser control in a .Net application since .Net was on version 1.0 and I've never had to call `Stop()` before `Navigate()`.  
I would say that unless you have a specific need to call `Stop()`, then you should be fine with just calling `Navigate()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through reflector, it doesn't appear that `Navigate()` calls `Stop()`, so no.

Comment: Could still be that the unmanaged code in the IE control calls `Stop()` internally, couldn't it?

Comment: Could be. And when you call Navigate(), it will inevitably stop the currently activity eventually but it's not the same as calling `Stop()` before hand, I don't think.